# Redirect to action doesn't work in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect

I have a controller `CMS` as you can see here :

```
  [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {



            return View(); // show the login page
        }
        UserRepository ObjUserRepository = new UserRepository();
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(DomainClass.User loginInfo, string returnUrl)
        {


            if (ObjUserRepository.FindBy(i => i.Email == loginInfo.Email & i.Password == loginInfo.Password).Any())
            {
                DomainClass.User objUser = ObjUserRepository.FindBy(i => i.Email == loginInfo.Email & i.Password == loginInfo.Password).FirstOrDefault();

                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loginInfo.Email, false);
                if (shouldRedirect(returnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }

                if (objUser.Pemission == "professor")
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { Area = "Teacher" });
                }


            }


        return View(loginInfo);
    }
```

I call this url `../cms/login`  and my `login` view appeared ,i enter the `username` and `password` ,this part of code is executed :

```
  if (objUser.Pemission == "professor")
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { Area = "Teacher" });
                }
```

But the mvc redirects me to Login page again ,but it should redirect me to `/teacher/home/index`

Comment: did you tried to breakpointed the Index controller of home controller, index action?

Comment: Yes i did .but nothing happens there

Comment: Once logged, can you go into the url without redirection in code behind? does it work?

Comment: @clement yes i can do

Comment: does it work properly?

Comment: beautiful coder has the answer. Think of put Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e){} in gloal asax in order to catch uncatched exceptions like that :-) it will be helpfull for you

Comment: @clement ok i will do that  right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { Area = "Teacher" });
```

To

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "Teacher" });
```

The `area` parameter is lower case.